# counting number of occurrences of a set of column values in one dataframe matching a second dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, count, apply

I have 2 dataframes where I want to count the number times the a of columns in the 2nd dataframe appears in the corresponding row at 1st dataframe :

```
> head(design)
  undIssue feelConf setup undContex undChang check
1        5        5     5         5        5     0
2        4        5     5         5        5     0
3        3        5     5         5        5     0
4        2        5     5         5        5     0
5        1        5     5         5        5     0
6        5        4     5         5        5     0

> head(actconjoint)
  undIssue feelConf setup undContex undChang
3        5        4     5         5        5
4        5        4     5         5        5
5        5        5     5         5        5
6        5        4     4         5        4
7        5        4     5         3        5
8        3        5     4         5        4
```

Check must receive the number of times I find the pattern at actconjoint in design.

So in this case the row 6 at design must receive 2 since it occurs twice at actconjoint.

I tried:

```
design$check <- 0

design$check <- 
  apply(design, 1, function(x) 
    ifelse(any(x[1] == actconjoint$undIssue & x[2] == actconjoint$feelConf & x[3] == actconjoint$setup & x[4] == actconjoint$undContex & x[5] == actconjoint$undChang), design$check<-design$check+1,design$check))
```

But the best I could be just to have "1"s into the check column!

Comment: Would this work? `sapply(1:nrow(design), function(x) sum(actconjoint[x,] == design[x,]))`

Comment: @Skaqqs Error in Ops.data.frame(actconjoint[x, ], design[x, ]) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: Did you try it again after considering the error (making sure both dataframes have the same number and order of columns i.e., remove "check")? Or, you could specify the columns in the square brackets `sapply(1:nrow(design), function(x) sum(actconjoint[x,cols] == design[x,cols]))`

Comment: It seems calculating. But I'm not sure for what rows the counts belong to. `> cols<-c("undIssue","feelConf","setup","undContex","undChang")
> sapply(1:nrow(design), function(x) sum(actconjoint[x,cols] == design[x,cols]))`

Comment: Great! Each element corresponds to a row in `design`. `design$check <- sapply(1:nrow(design), function(x) sum(actconjoint[x,cols] == design[x,cols]))` is the result you're expecting, I think... EDIT: nevermind, I just realized I misunderstood your question. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a unique key for both the dataframes and count how many times each occur in another dataframe.

```
key1 <- do.call(paste, design[names(actconjoint)])
key2 <- do.call(paste, actconjoint)
design$check <- sapply(key1, function(x) sum(x == key2))
```